# How to create enought traffic to bring my router down?

Tags: router, wireless-router, nat

In our office we have a TP Link TL-ER604W router. Sometimes the router runs into problems and nothing in the network works anymore, also not the connection to the router itself. The only possibility to make it run again is to restart the device.

There is no Logfiles that I could use and no other information that helps me to find out why this is happening. There is approximatly up to 15 or 20 devices connected to the router.

My thought was that the CPU-Capacity of the Router runs out so I tried to overload it. I opened variouse videostream on different devices, copied large files inside and outside the network and used the command `iperf3 -c XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -t 1200 -P 128` but the router kept working.

So my next approach was to overfill the NAT-table (which seems to be a problem on my home router) which I only did by opening multiple websites in my browser but the max number of NAT entries was just 500. And the router far from having a problem.

My questions are now:
Is there a better tool to overload the router in variouse scenarios, especially the NAT requests? 
Is my approach right or am I missing something important?

Comment: how often does it happens? Do you restart it otherwise regularly? We had similar problems in the past and we could solve it with a time switch powering off router for half an hour in every night,

Comment: Sometimes multiple times a day. Sometimes a whole week not. What do you think it was in your case? Heat?

Comment: How big is this *"office"*?  Is a consumer-grade/SOHO router appropriate for the network load of this *"office"*?  Is the load wired or wireless? Videostreams are not that taxing to a router; you only think that because latency issues cause glitching/stuttering.  I used to overload a network device by `ping`ing it from several terminals from several (UNIX, not Windows) hosts.  (Nowadays there's also the flood mode in Linux.)  Of course this would only test the LAN-side of your router.

Comment: 4 workspaces (2x Win, 2x Ubuntu), 1-3 Android phones, 1 NAS Server, 2 printers, 1 telephone system and another router where i don't have any information how many devices are connected. Only one workstation and the phones connect via wifi. I will give it a try with the ping flood mode. Meanwhile we mounted a time switch to switch the device off once at night.

Comment: Yes - The tool you need is IxChariot from Ixia.  It'll load your AP.  It's a bit pricey though...